# Need help using php to detect iOS version to serve correct favicon

Tags: php, ios, version

Given the fact that iOS 7 is changing the look of icons, I'm trying to figure out a way of detecting which iOS version visitors to our site are using, and thus serve up the appropriate icon for the device... particularly for when pinning to home screen. What I have at present is :

```
function add_theme_favicon() {
echo '<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" >';
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPhone OS 7_\d') !== false) { 
echo  '<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="' . TF_FAV . '/new_favicon_256x256.png" >';
}
else {
    echo '<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="' . TF_FAV . '/favicon_256x256.png" >';
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_theme_favicon');
```

Unfortunately something isn't right as the the same image is getting served to all versions of iOS. Can someone point me in the right direction on this one?

Answer (score 1):

Function `strpos` doesn't use regular expressions. You need to find `'iPhone OS 7_'` instead of `'iPhone OS 7_\d'`. As you can test `HTTP_USER_AGENT` doesn't contain `\d`.

Comment: Ah awesome... nice spot. Now I just discovered that only works for iPhone and not the iPad etc. Is there a way to define by iOS version only, irrespective of the device? I know I can use || to declare each possible iOS device, but the whole point of this exercise is to minimise the amount of icons being served as well as stripping back the code required to do so.